# JCombobox with actionperformed in another actionperformed

Tags: java, jcombobox

I'm trying to make a Combobox with actionperformed in another actionperformed. The idea is that you start with a screen with a button, and after the button is clicked the combobox is added. When I try to add the combobox, the error says "vlaggenlijst cannot be resolved to a variable".

Here is the code where I make the combobox:

```
JComboBox vlaggenlijst = new JComboBox(vlaggen);
vlaggenlijst.setSelectedIndex(0);
vlaggenlijst.addActionListener(this);
```

This is the code inside the actionPerformed:

```
if(event.getSource() == b1) {
        Container parentft = FirstText.getParent();
        parentft.remove(FirstText);
        parentft.validate();
        parentft.repaint();

        Title.setText("Vlaggen");

        Container parentb1 = b1.getParent();
        parentb1.remove(b1);
        parentb1.validate();
        parentb1.repaint();

        add(vlaggenlijst, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        add(Picture, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        if(event.getSource() == vlaggenlijst){
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)event.getSource();
            String vlagnaam = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            updateLabel(vlagnaam);
        }
}
```

Can anyone please help me, I really don't know where I went wrong. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: ``I'm trying to make a Combobox with actionperformed in another actionperformed. `` - what ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `JComboBox vlaggenlijst` as a field not local variable eg:

`private JComboBox vlaggenlijst = null;`

Comment: Thank you, the errors are gone now. Only thing is, the combobox that is shown now is empty, so after the button click there is nothing shown. With the line "JComboBox vlaggenlijst = new JComboBox(vlaggen);" I added a String to it.

Comment: IDK what `vlaggen` is but is could be for example an `String[]` with possible options.

Comment: vlaggen is "String[] vlaggen = { ALL OPTIONS };" But when i added your line the combobox isn't shown